# Facebook comment.create on mobile phone not working

Tags: facebook, mobile-safari, facebook-comments

I've got a problem with Facebook `comment.create` subscription.

The problem is that the event is not fired up in the mobile browser but in the desktop browser, it all works fine.

Why doesn't this work on mobile?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'XXXXXXX',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function (response) {
        alert("comment created");
    });

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a [bug on Facebook's end](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/604681079553717)